# Security Issue on many user accounts (Java, Tomcat, Web)

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a few pages on my server with different roles and users, and configured Basic Authentication.

When I succesfully login first page and then trying to open another my page (in another tab) then I just see the error: HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied.
To succesfully open that another page I need to close and re-open my browser.

Expected behaviour: I open my another page in new tab and I see new login dialog for entering login and password for new page.

These is my configuration:

tomcat-users.xml:

```
  <role rolename="Role1"/>
  <role rolename="Role2"/>

  <user username="user1" password="pass1" roles="Role1"/>
  <user username="user2" password="pass2" roles="Role2"/>
```

part of web.xml:

```
 <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>Info Page</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/DeploymentInfoService</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>Role1</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
     </security-constraint>

     <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>RSS Feeds</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/RssFeedService</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>Role2</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
     </security-constraint>

     <security-role>
      <role-name>Role1</role-name>
     </security-role>

     <security-role>
      <role-name>Role2</role-name>
     </security-role>

     <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>OnJava Application</realm-name>
     </login-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You limit each page for a single role, and you have 2 users, each one with a different role.
Threfore, user1 can only access the DeploymentInfoService page, and user2 can only access the RssFeedService page. If you want any of them to access another page, you must either grant them another role, or allow more roles on the page.

Comment: No, you have an incorrect meaning of my problem. I am trying to access another page by different username (and just forget the previous page), but I cannot it. Browser does not popup me login/password form, I just get an error described above